# choose folder window in php or jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

i want **Choose specific path folder** to save file.
for that  i want click on **butto**n and it should show **folder choose** option.

Comment: and why **don't you do it** then and consult us with any actual problems you encounter on the way?

Comment: @Queen you are really Queen you just order and "Stackoverflow user" give you the ready code to you ???

Post your Code what you do

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" onchange="selectFolder(event)" webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory multiple />
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectFolder(e) {
    var theFiles = e.target.files;
    var relativePath = theFiles[0].webkitRelativePath;
    var folder = relativePath.split("/");
    alert(folder[0]);
}
</script>
```